# Error SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio - DQS - System.NotImplementedException

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2017, data-quality-services

When I create a Connection to DQS in an SSIS Project I get System.NotImplementedException error after the build. I am using Visual Studio 2017

Running SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio 2017

This is the error I get:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not
>   implemented.    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Interop.ProjectInterop.ReferencePackage(Package
>   package, String packageLocation)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.PackageItem.Load(IDTSEvents events)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.PackageItem.get_Package()    at
>   Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsProjectBuilder.IncrementalBuildThroughObj(IOutputWindow
>   outputWindow)    at
>   Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsProjectBuilder.BuildIncremental(IOutputWindow
>   outputWindow)         0

Comment: Do you use some packages? Uninstall and reinstall them

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I just realized that I am missing all the DTS packages. When can I download and install them. Thanks for the help

Comment: @MgcoboGwampi, I got the same error also. Can you add a link to where you download a DTS package?I'm very new to SSIS so please forgive me for my ignorance.

Also, I'm running VS 2017 against SQL 2012.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017.

Comment: Did you mange to get it working?

Comment: Not yet, I think i'm going to give up for now. I wish you the best of luck @MgcoboGwampi.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue by Microsoft.
It can be resolved by using an older version of `SSDT`.
Works fine with `SSDT FOR vs2017 15.9.0`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/previous-releases-of-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt-and-ssdt-bi?view=sql-server-2017